# I can't seem to figure out how to get my ng-repeat to work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### ng-repeat is commented out on chrome inspect

I can't seem to figure out how to get my ng-repeat to work.  I can see that the correct information is scoped properly, but when I inspect the HTML in dev tools, the first line below is commented out and the cards don't show up.  Any suggestions?

```
<div ng-repeat="matchedArtist in matchedArtists">
    <div class="centerPandora">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-med-12">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="firstinfo">
                <img src="#" />
                <div class="profileinfo">
                  <h1>{{ matchedArtist.artist }}</h1>
                  <h3>{{ matchedArtist.date }}</h3>
                  <h4>{{ matchedArtist.venue }}</h4>
                  <p class="bio"></p>
                  <a href="#">
                    <font color="black">Click for event details</font>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="badgescard info"><span id="days"></span><span 
id="hours"></span><span id="minutes"></span><span id="seconds"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
```

```
'use strict';

var concertList = 
angular.module('concertList').controller('ConcertListCtrl', 
function($scope){
    function hideLogin($scope) {
        $scope.advstatus = true;
    };
    $scope.matchedArtists = matchedArtists
});
```

### UPDATE

[Here is a screenshot of the AngularJS scope showing events are being scoped properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heSdh.png)

[image: 1]

Comment: What is `$scope.matchedArtists = matchedArtists` supposed to do? Have you tried debugging your code? Added some console.log() statements?

Comment: The `ng-repeat` builds DOM using a comment node as its base. If the repeat expression contains no data, no DOM will be built. How do you know the correct information is scoped properly? The problem described suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you must to be sure that yours controllers works properly and goes inside html template.

Than $scope.matchedArtists - is an Array of objects in yours case

```
$scope.matchedArtists = [{artist: 'ártist', date: 'date', venue: 'venue '},
{artist: 'ártist2', date: 'date2', venue: 'venue2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Debugging AngularJS Problems

To quickly test the variable on scope:

```
matchedArtists={{matchedArtists | json}} scope={{$id}}
<div ng-repeat="matchedArtist in matchedArtists">
    <div class="centerPandora">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-med-12">
```

Using the inspection console, click on the element of interest:

```
>scope=angular.element($0).scope()
>console.dir(scope)
```

There are several possible reasons the data is not showing:

1. The template is part of an isolate scope;
2. The controller is on a sibling element;
3. The controller was instantiated with `controllerAs` syntax;